# How to get the ability to make a windows kernel driver on Visual Studio

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, kernel, driver

this is my first stack overflow question and im currently trying to make a Windows KMD on Visual studio. I tried using this guide (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/writing-a-very-small-kmdf--driver) but i cant select the "driver" option on project type and i dont have any options for selecting any of the kernel mode drivers. Im guessing this is because i havent selected certain things on the visual studio installer that are used for kernel mode driver development, what should i select and add on the installer to add these options? i already went through the whole list but didnt have any success so if someone could help it would really be appreciated

Tried adding the things related to Windows kmd development on the visual studio installer and some quick google searches

expected to find a solution to this problem but had no success

Comment: All you need are Visual C/C++, Windows SDK and  Windows WDK.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind i found  a fix to it. just follow this guide for a more detailed explanation, ill also add a TLDR for this guide aswell:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk

TLDR:
download the windows SDK from this link after checking you have the right stuff installed in VS: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-sdk/
download WDK from this link (or you can click the link on the tutorial link above) https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2196230

launch visual studio (make sure its not too outdated or it doesnt work) and you will be able to make drivers for Windows